# Vite: Set `assetFileName` based upon directory name

Tags: vite, rollupjs

Given the project structure below, Vite will output both CSS files as `index.<hash>.css` which makes them difficult to debug. I'd like to alter the config to use the directory name if the file name is `index`:

```
src/
--pages/
----Home/
------index.jsx
------style.css
----NotFound/
------index.jsx
------style.css
```

Unfortunately, the param of `assetFileNames` seems to be quite barren of usable information about the source location.

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                    console.log(assetInfo);
                    return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
                },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```
{
  name: 'index.css',
  source: '<My CSS content>',
  type: 'asset'
}
```

Is there any way to get further context from `assetInfo`, such as the original file path?

`chunkFileNames`, for instance, gets the `facadeModuleId` property which contains the original file path which is incredibly useful here; it ensures `NotFound/index.jsx` is output as `NotFound-<hash>.js`, rather than `index-<hash>.js`:

```js
chunkFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
    const name = assetInfo.name == 'index'
        ? path.basename(path.dirname(assetInfo.facadeModuleId))
        : assetInfo.name;
    return `${name}-[hash].js`;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4724